# How to get the value of params inside jenkins pipeline stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

How to access parameters values inside different stages in Jenkins pipeline.
So far I have done:

```
env_vars = 'Initial value'

pipeline {
    agent {label 'master'}
    stages {
        stage('Inject-Env-Vars') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env_vars = params.collect{string(name: it.key, value: it.value)}   //Collecting all the params here
                }  
            }
        }
        stage('add_env_variable') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env_vars.add(string(name: 'Change_Reason', value: "sam")) ////Adding an extra param
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Parent') {
            parallel {
                stage('RCP') {
                    steps {
                        echo "$env_vars"
                        echo "${env_vars.Change_Reason}"   //// want to print value of Change_Reason
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] { (RCP)
[Pipeline] echo
[@string(name=Change_Reason,value=sam)]
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch RCP
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field org.jenkinsci.plugins.structs.describable.UninstantiatedDescribable Change_Reason
```

Please let me know if there is a way to get the param value in different stages.

Answer (score 0):

`env_vars` seems to be an Array and you expect to access it as a Map.